# Is it possible to find the password of a Zip file if you have all content that inside it on a separate folder?

Tags: encryption, zip

I'm trying to find the password of a Zip file. I already have the content of the Zip file on a separate folder. But I want to find the password of the Zip. Would the files in the separate folder help? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Is the Zip archive encrypted using AES or using ZipCrypt?

Comment: @user1686 The Zip archive is `ZipCrypto Deflate` and `ZipCrypto Store`